# How to add a 'Load More..' option for blogs in html or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading blogs from a SQL Database and some are quite long. So I want to limit each blog to about 30(Can be more or less) words and then add a `Load More` link at the end, which would then load the rest of the blog for the user to see.

The blogs get retrieved via a jQuery AJAX call. The received data then gets ran through a `for loop` set on the length of the JSON array getting returned. And finally populated with a `.append(<The html to be appended>);`. So this is how it looks:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<url to api>",
    success: function (data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            blogsBlock.append(`
            <div class="blog">
                <div class="blog-header">`+ data[i].Name + `</div>
                <div class="blog-content">
                    <div class="blog-content-inner">
                        `+ data[i].Blog + `
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="blog-footer">
                    Uploaded: `+ data[i].Date+ `
                </div>
            </div>
            `);
        }
    }
});
```

So again, I want to limit the blogs to about 30 words and then append a `Load More` button next to it which will load the rest of the blog for the user when clicked.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question correctly. If this is the case of long blog text, then you can display the limited content by adding min height on the blog div.

Comment: Do you have long and short description? - Or just a one description?

Comment: You are loading 'Blogs" (list of blogs), and then you want to limit them by 30 words. Is that what you asked?

Comment: @santanubera, Yes

Comment: @yfain, Does that really matter more than helping someone out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to display list of Blogs and limit them by 30 words(Instead of counting words, you should count characters, like 150 characters), there are common two ways you can solve your problem -

#### Solution 1

You should add a column to the DB table which can hold a short description of the Blog, or title of the blog, then you fetch it from the server and display It. This short description either can be taken from the user or can be calculated from the actual blog (like, first 150 character from the blog content) when you insert the blog data to the database.

#### Solution 2

If you already have lots of blogs in your DB and don't have a column for short description, you can limit the characters while you fetch data from DB. For example -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`text`, 1, 150) as shortDesc FROM BlogTable;
```

Comment: So then if someone clicks the `Load More` button I just run a quick ajax and replace the blogs text?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. My answer just limits the data coming from the database. Instead of fetching whole content of the blog just to show two or three lines, you 
should limit the data when you fetch them from MySQL. And "Load More" button has nothing to do with this. Load more operation is completely independent from the above solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a javascript based solution, you can also just the substring function for strings to limit the shown part as well as put the rest of it into a span. Then, when you click on the "...more" you just remove the class from the Element.

html:

```
<div class="blog" id="result"></div>
```

css:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.more:hover {
  color: #f00;
  cursor: 'pointer'!important;
}

.more.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

js:

```
let blog = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = blog.substr(0, 50) + '<span class="more">... more</span><span class="restOfBlog hide">' + blog.substr(50) + '</span>';

let blogElements = document.getElementsByClassName("more");
for (let i = 0; i < blogElements.length; i++){
    blogElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this);
    let parentElement = this.closest(".blog");
    console.log(parentElement);
    parentElement.querySelector(".restOfBlog").classList.remove("hide");
    parentElement.querySelector(".more").classList.add("hide");
  })
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hypoLz7j/1/)